# universal app ipad not showing colors

Tags: iphone, ipad, colors, universal

Hey guys. So I converted an iphone app to a universal app, and when I try to change the background colors, e.g., view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];, it would change while running on the iphone. However, the ipad will only show gray. Does anyone else get this? Same thing for interface builder.

Thanks,

Comment: Now when I load it to the device, an image won't show up. This is all kinds of horrible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to set the backgroundView to nil as I believe the iPad has a default gray gradient view which will override the background color.